# crop transparent space from custom drawing View when saving

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am working on an application where the user can draw on the screen.

I have a custom `View` called: `DrawingView` that uses a `Canvas` object to draw.

I am able to successfully draw, and save the drawing as a `PNG`.

**Problem**

The problem that I am running into is that when I save the drawing it saves the entire screen, with all the transparent space around the drawing.

for example:

[image: House Drawing with white space]

**Desired Outcome**

What I am hoping to achieve is a way to crop the transparent space from the drawing.

for example:

[image: House Drawing with no white space]

**DrawingView**

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
    private final static String TAG = DrawingView.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final float TOLERANCE = 5f;
    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 15f;

    private final ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> mPaths = new ArrayList<>();

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mX;
    private float mY;



    public DrawingView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);

        mPaths.add(new Pair<>(mPath, new Paint(mPaint)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);

        if (!mPaths.isEmpty()) {
            canvas.drawPath(mPaths.get(mPaths.size() - 1).first, mPaths.get(mPaths.size() - 1).second);
        }
    }

    public void save(String path) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(path);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, writer);
            writer.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startTouch(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);

        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        mPaths.add(new Pair<>(mPath, new Paint(mPaint)));
        invalidate();
    }

    private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(x - mY);

        if (dx >= TOLERANCE || dy >= TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    private void upTouch() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        mPaths.add(new Pair<>(mPath, new Paint(mPaint)));
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startTouch(x, y);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                moveTouch(x, y);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                upTouch();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> paths = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Pair pair : mPaths) {
            paths.add(pair);
        }
        mPaths.removeAll(paths);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCanvas.getWidth(), mCanvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

So I used the class `RectF` to keep track of my min and max X,Y coordinates when drawing the image.

I created a `RectF` object in my constructor called: `mDrawnAreaRect` then I added a method to find the min and max X,Y values called `findMinMax`:

```
 private void findMinMax(int x, int y) {
    if (x < mDrawnAreaRect.left) { //min x
        mDrawnAreaRect.left = x;
    }

    if (y >  mDrawnAreaRect.top) { //max y
        mDrawnAreaRect.top = y;
    }

    if (x >  mDrawnAreaRect.right) { //max x
        mDrawnAreaRect.right = x;
    }

    if (y <  mDrawnAreaRect.bottom) { //min y
        mDrawnAreaRect.bottom = y;
    }
}
```

I then implemented this method at the bottom of Override `onTouchEvent` method like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startTouch(x, y);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            moveTouch(x, y);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upTouch();
            break;
    }

    findMinMax((int) x, (int) y); //IMPLEMENTED HERE
    return true;
}
```

finally when I save the Bitmap I use the left, top, right, and bottom values from `mDrawnAreaRect` to crop out the transparent space in a method called: `cropBitmap`:

```
private Bitmap cropBitmap() {
    int minX = mDrawnAreaRect.left <= 0 ? 0 : (int) mDrawnAreaRect.left;
    int maxY = mDrawnAreaRect.top > mBitmap.getHeight() ? mBitmap.getHeight() : (int) mDrawnAreaRect.top;
    int maxX = mDrawnAreaRect.right > mBitmap.getWidth() ? mBitmap.getWidth() : (int) mDrawnAreaRect.right;
    int minY = mDrawnAreaRect.bottom <= 0 ? 0 : (int) mDrawnAreaRect.bottom;

    int width = maxX - minX;
    int height = maxY - minY;

    width = width > mBitmap.getWidth() ? mBitmap.getWidth() : width;
    height = height > mBitmap.getHeight() ? mBitmap.getHeight() : height;

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, minX, minY, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, but maybe you can store each point's x and y that is being drawn. Then, you can take the smallest x, largest x, smallest y, and largest y in a list of drawn points. Finally, with this data, you may be able to find the width, height, and location of the desired image (which is like creating the rectangle around the image you drew). From there, hopefully you can figure out a way to resize the screen or save the image using the data from the points.

I know this isn't a code for code solution, but it's just an idea I think you should try!

Comment: I thought about this using RectF, but im not sure how to implement it correctly! I will continue to look into this. Thanks though!